# Xamarin.Forms - How to navigate to a tabbed page child page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm still fairly new to Xamarin.Forms and app building in general so please be gentle.

Currently I'm using a Tabbed Page to handle my main navigation and I have 3 tabs as soon as the user logs in. One of the tabs is called "AccountPage". From the account page you can go to a profile page and update profile information. After the user finishes updating profile information and saving I currently do a Navigation.PushAsync back to the account page.

What I'm wanting to do is actually have it navigate back to the main tabbed page but show the account child page...if that makes sense. Basically I want the account page to display but to also have the tabs displayed for navigation (which it currently doesn't since I'm just navigating directly to the account page).

Is there a way to navigate to a tabbed page child? Something like

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage().Child(new AccountPage()))
```

Comment: from the docs, "it's not recommended to place a TabbedPage into a NavigationPage"

Comment: Is it common place then to usually have a "Home" button or link then on child pages that would take the user back to the tabbed page?

Comment: No, if you have a TabbedPage it is usually the root so it is always visible

Comment: Sorry, I said child page when I meant a separate view that isn't part of a child page. I get the part of having the tabbed page visible all the time when looking at its direct children but I guess I'm having a hard time working around what the navigation looks like when you're on a view that isn't a direct child.

Comment: generally you would have a NavigationPage within the Tab, and then use that to navigate between child pages within a single tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can wrap the tabbed child page into `NavigationPage`,for example:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageWithNavigationPage;assembly=TabbedPageWithNavigationPage" x:Class="TabbedPageWithNavigationPage.MainPage">
  <NavigationPage Title="Schedule" IconImageSource="schedule.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:AccountPage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
  <local:TodayPage />
  <local:SettingsPage />
</TabbedPage>
```

Then you can go to page `ProfilePage` by following code:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync (new ProfilePage());
```

And come back to `AccountPage` by using code:

```
 await Navigation.PopAsync ();
```

Comment: thanks jessie :) i was actually going to answer myself until i saw yours. the PopAsync() method is what i needed to do instead of doing another Push.

Comment: Congrats, happy coding...   :)